# Previous class gets called when calling the next class

Tags: java, class, jbutton

**I am not experienced, and only 14 tears old!**

I made a little application, that would quiz me. Basically I would put in questions and answers in a notepad like this:

```
H
Hydrogen
O
Oxygen
K
Potassium
```

The program would sort the words like so↓, and display them in a `TextArea` with a `ScrollPane`

```
H    =    Hydrogen
O    =    Oxygen
K    =    Potassium
```

On the bottom theres, a ``` JButton("Start Test"), and it would ask you the questions in order. E.g. ``H means? ``` `O Means?` `K Means?`  and then it would give you feedback E.g. `Wrong! H means Hydrogen`, or `Correct!`

here are the two classes! `GUI` is just simply the GUI. and the `test` is the class responsible for the testing

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
        //JFrame components
        public static JButton btn = new JButton("Start Test");
        public static JPanel panelBtn = new JPanel();
        public static JPanel panelTxt = new JPanel();
        public static JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
        public static JScrollPane  scroll = new JScrollPane(txt);

        static String[] words;

        static String link = "words.txt";

        //constructor
        public GUI()
        {   

            //title
        setTitle("Test");
        //size
        setSize(400,400);

            //layout
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //on close
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //OTHER
        txt.setLineWrap(true);
        txt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txt.setEditable(false);
        txt.setBackground(Color.white);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        //border for panelTxt
       LineBorder b1 = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        LineBorder b2 = new LineBorder(panelBtn.getBackground() ,5);
        txt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b2,b1));
       //actionListnere
        btn.addActionListener(new lst());

        //add
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelBtn.add(btn);
        add(panelBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //visible
            setVisible(true);
    }

    //action listener for btn
    private class lst implements ActionListener
    {   
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        new test(words);
                    GUI g = new GUI() ; 
                    g.setVisible(false);    

            }
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    new GUI();
    final int ARRAY_LEN = getArrayLength();         
    words = makeArray(ARRAY_LEN);
    displayArray(words);

    btn.setEnabled(true);

}


//get the length of the array, using hasNext from Scanner class 
private static int getArrayLength() throws IOException 
{
    File file = new File(link);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    int len = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {   
        scanner.nextLine();
        len++;
    }

     final int ARRAY_LEN = len +1;

     return ARRAY_LEN;
}

//declares and initializes String array, with length of ARRAY_LEN
private static String[] makeArray(final int ARRAY_LEN) throws     FileNotFoundException 
{
    String[] words = new String[ARRAY_LEN];

    int value = 0;
    int count = ARRAY_LEN;

    words[value] = null;
    count--;
    value++;

    File file = new File(link);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    do
    {
        words[value] = scanner.nextLine();
        count--;
        value++;
    }while(count != 0);

    return words;
}

//displays the array in text area
private static void displayArray(String[] words)
{

    int len = words.length - 1;

    int i = 0;
    i++;
    txt.setText(words[i]);
    i++;
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + "\t=");
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + "\t" + words[i]);
    do
    {
    i ++;
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + "\n\n" + words[i]);
    i++;
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + "\t=");
    txt.setText(txt.getText() + "\t" + words[i]);


    }while(i != len);

}
}
```

Class 2

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.util.Random;

public class test extends GUI
{
public static String[] words;

//constructor
public test(String[] word)
{
    words = word;
    main(word);

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int len = words.length;

    boolean first = true;
    for(int i = 0; i != len; i++)
    {
        if(first == true)   //to skip null
        {
            i++;
            first = false; 
        }

        String question = words[i];
        i++;
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question+ " is?");
        String rightAnswer = words[i];

        if(answer.equals(rightAnswer))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong! " + question +" means " + rightAnswer);
        }
    }
}

}
```

**So here is the problem**

Whenever I press the Button, it starts the test, but a new window from `GUI` class is created, and `setVisible(false)` doesn't actually do anything.

So there are 2 problmes;
1 `setVisible(false)` doesn't work.
2 a new window gets created  at `ButtonClikced()`, so there are 2 identical windows, and closing one, closes the other too.

**Please help because I don't know what to do**

Comment: Your code looks like you may be putting the proverbial cart before the horse.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ??

Comment: Here is piece of free advice for the future "never have static fields to mutable objects".

Comment: You're trying to delve into a somewhat complex corner of Java, here Swing GUI's, but don't yet understand basic Java oops concepts including use of instance variables and inheritance. If you were my student, I'd suggest scrapping this code and have you start over, following good object-oriented principles.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok. So if I started over, what would I do differently?

Comment: 1. Get rid of all those static fields and instead use almost exclusively instance fields. 2. Create a non-GUI Question class, one that has non-static fields and methods. 3. Create a non-GUI class that holds an `ArrayList<Question>` collection of questions 4. Create a class to read from the text file and fills the collection with Question objects. 5. Create a GUI that uses the collection of questions class to display questions and get input from the user .... Use Java to its full object-oriented advantage.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see, but why non-GUI? is GUI just fine??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels removing GUI will make a hole new program, and I like this one the way it is, I just want to fix the problmes

Comment: You need a whole new program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels When you say use object-oriented advantage, do you mean to make class for all the operations, rather than methods

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `new GUI ();` from the main method.
In your code, button was invisibled when action performe. But inthis time `GUI` object also was created. When the `GUI` object is created, it `main` method will be executed. There you are going to visible the button.
So change the 
`btn.setEnabled(true);` to required another method.

Try this following code,

```
//main
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final int ARRAY_LEN = getArrayLength();         
    words = makeArray(ARRAY_LEN);
    displayArray(words);

    // btn.setEnabled(true);

}
```